# How can I mount a lowerdir into a specific subdirectory with overlayfs?

Tags: overlayfs

I want to mount the following directories using overlayfs:

```
(lowerdir) /chroot in /merged
(lowerdir) /home   in /merged/home
(upperdir) /tmpfs  in /merged
```

...so that the resulting merged directory is a COW system that contains both the /chroot and /home.

I cannot find any way to do that.

1) Trying multiple lower dirs:

```
mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/chroot:/home,upperdir=/tmpfs,workdir=/workdir overlay /merged
ls /merged
```

==> failure, the /home contents merge with the /chroot contents directly in /merged without getting inside a /merged/home subdirectory.

2) Trying bind-mounts:

```
mount --bind /home /chroot/home
mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/chroot,upperdir=/tmpfs,workdir=/workdir overlay /merged
ls /merged/home
```

==> empty, the /chroot/home submount contents do not show up in /merged/home.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: According to the answer this was a bug, now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem tonight, however I was using `/`, `/usr`, `/var` as the test since I wanted to capture changes to the filesytem from a package install and skim it out of the OverlayFS 'upperdir'.

I figured out that OverlayFS wasn't designed for this, then I remembered about unionfs-fuse...  I also saw that OverlayFS could use itself as a `lowerdir`, so I took a shot with using unionfs-fuse instead and it worked.

Keep in mind this is just a quick 'lab' PoC test, and I'm sure you'll want to tweak the unionfs-fuse options quite a bit for your needs...

```
mkdir merged union upper work
sudo unionfs-fuse /=RO:/usr=RO:/var=RO:/home=RO union
sudo mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=union,upperdir=upper,workdir=work merged
sudo echo test > merged/newtestfile
ls merged/newtestfile # exists
ls upper/newtestfile # exists
```

Overall, the solution is a bit twisted/demented but it seems to work ok at least for what I was trying to accomplish by isolating the changes that could be skimmed from the ./upper directory.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but both unionfs and aufs were working fine, the problem was specifically with overlayfs. Also sorry for the late reply, I didn't receive a notification email.

Comment: The command `unionfs-fuse /=RO:/usr=RO:/var=RO:/home=RO union` seems quite random in the sense that `union` will contain the content from all four directories mixed together. Why would I want the content of `/usr`, `/var` and `/home` mixed into `/`?! - Being new to unionfs it took me some time to figure out that this should be separate mount calls, more like here: https://github.com/rpodgorny/unionfs-fuse/blob/master/examples/unionfs-fuse-nfs-root#L90-L106. Man page here: https://linux.die.net/man/8/unionfs

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make a separate overlay for what should end up as `/chroot/home` somewhere else, then bind it on top of the overlay for `/chroot`

Answer (score -2):

We committed the solution in:
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ltsp-upstream/ltsp/ltsp-trunk/revision/2652

Comment: Can you expand your answer here a bit to explain in principle what you did, or even better include the full solution?